# Mysql Multiple Aggregate Function based on Different Where Clause

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, where-clause

I have the following mysql query:

```
Select id, sum(sales_qty) as 'Todays Sales' from sales
Where date = '2015-03-17'
Group by id
```

Now in the same query I want to have another aggregate function of *sales_qty* but with different where clause. On a separate query it would look like:

```
Select id, sum(sales_qty) as 'Till Date Sales' from sales
Where date between '2015-03-01' and '2015-03-17'
Group by id
```

How can I get the intended results in a single query?

thanks...it's working...now what I have in hand is a bit more complicated...let me explain:

First Query:

*Select id, sum(sales_qty) as 'Todays Sales Qty', sum(sales_value) as 'Todays Sales Value' from sales
Where date = '2015-03-19'
Group by id*

Second query:

*Select id, sum(sales_value) as 'Till Date Sales Value' from sales
Where date between '2015-03-01' and '2015-03-19'
Group by id*

Intended Output columns (using single query):

*id, Todays Sales Qty, Todays Sales Value, Till Date Sales Value*

Is it possible? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do this in a subquery:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.`Todays Sales`,
    t2.`Till Date Sales`
FROM
    (
        Select id, sum(sales_qty) as 'Todays Sales' from sales
        Where date = '2015-03-17'
        Group by id
    )t1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        Select id, sum(sales_qty) as 'Till Date Sales' from sales
        Where date between '2015-03-01' and '2015-03-17'
        Group by id

    )t2 ON
    t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: thanks...it's working...now what I have in hand is a bit more complicated...let me explain:

First Query:
Select id, sum(sales_qty) as 'Todays Sales Qty', sum(sales_value) as 'Todays Sales Value' from sales
Where date = '2015-03-19'
Group by id

Second query:
Select id, sum(sales_value) as 'Till Date Sales Value' from sales
Where date between '2015-03-01' and '2015-03-19'
Group by id

Intended Output columns (using single query):
ID, Todays Sales Qty, Todays Sales Value, Till Date Sales Value

Is it possible? Please help. Thanks in advance.